# kotlin boolean retrofit from api

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

```
Response
{
   "success": true,
   "total_duration": "0 Hours : 0 Minutes",
   "form_api": "http://review-raihan-restriction-package.dev.aplikasidev.com/api/v1/webform_auths/",
   "is_webform": true, (jika is_webform=false maka user tidak bisa akses webview cwf jadi card pada timeline daily journey ketika di tap tidak memunculkan webview cwf)
   "data": []
}
```

i want make boolean check validate in is_webform if is_webform = false then the user cannot access the cwf webview so the card on the daily journey timeline when tapped does not display the cwf webview how to do this? need help guys thank you

Comment: need help bro, u can ask me for detail in comment :')

Answer (score 0):

I think you need, convert response to Model.
After check condition is_webform to disable touch webview.

Comment: webviewUrl = when (checkoutState && restrictformstate) {
            true -> {
                "${apiForm}${journeyId}/edit?token=${greenHCMProfile.getUser()?.token}"

            }
            false -> {
                "${Formweb}${journeyId}?token=${greenHCMProfile.getUser()?.token}"
                "${Formweb}${journeyId}/edit?token=${greenHCMProfile.getUser()?.token}"


            }

Comment: can u help me??